# ckeditor how to allow for .insertHtml("<customTag myAttr='value'"></customTag>")

Tags: ckeditor

```
var currentDialog = CKEDITOR.dialog.getCurrent();
currentDialog._.editor.insertHtml("<customTag myAttr='var'></customTag>");
```

Throws an error, `TypeError: Cannot read property 'isBlock' of undefined`

If I try `.insertHtml("<span>hello</span>")` it works just fine.

How can I change ckeditor to allow me to specify my own custom html tags via `.insertHtml()`? I'd love to just change it to be something like `<span class='custom'...` or something like that, but I'm having to deal with legacy CMS articles. Using latest ckeditor. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

1. You need to modify `CKEDITOR.dtd` object so editor will know this tag and correctly parse HTML and process DOM:

   ```
   CKEDITOR.dtd.customtag = { em:1 };        // List of tag names it can contain.
   CKEDITOR.dtd.$block.customtag = 1;        // Choose $block or $inline.
   CKEDITOR.dtd.body.customtag = 1;          // Body may contain customtag.
   ```
2. You need to allow for this tag and its styles/attrs/classes in [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/plugin_sdk_integration_with_acf):

   ```
   editor.filter.allow( 'customtag[myattr]', 'myfeature' );
   ```

Unfortunately, due to some caching, in certain situations you cannot modify DTD object after CKEditor is loaded - you need to modify it when it is created. So to do that:

1. Clone the [CKEditor repository](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev) or [CKEditor presets repository](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-presets).
2. Modify [core/dtd.js](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/dtd.js) code.
3. And build your minified package following instructions in `README.md` - the only requirements are Java (sorry - Google Closure Compiler :P) and Bash.

**PS.** That error should not be thrown when unknown element is inserted, so I reported http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10339 and to solve this inconvenience http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/10340.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around this issue with a combination of createFromHtml() and insertElement()

```
CKEDITOR.replace('summary', { ... });

var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.summary; 
editor.on('key', function(ev) {
    if (ev.data.keyCode == 9) { // TAB
        var tabHtml = '<span style="white-space:pre">&#09;</span>';
        var tabElement = CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml(tabHtml, editor.document);
        editor.insertElement(tabElement);
    }
}
```