# CKEditor for ASP.NET & custom tags

Tags: asp.net, ckeditor

I need to edit an ascx file's content with CKEditor. The content of ascx is mostly pure html code. It also has a custom tags in it (I use a custom framework and its own custom tags, ie: )

CKEditor erases those custom tags automatically (since they are not valid HTML codes).

How can I add/define framework's custom tags into CKEditor so it would not erase them.

PS: those custom tags don't need to be rendered in HTML view as long as they stay in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify CKEDITOR.dtd object so editor will know this tag and correctly parse HTML and process DOM. See [ckeditor how to allow for .insertHtml("<customTag myAttr='value'"></customTag>")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066556/ckeditor-how-to-allow-for-inserthtmlcustomtag-myattr-value-customtag)

Comment: I already saw that post; 2 issues:

- I don't have a dtd.js file (or any file with 'dtd')
- "build your minified package with java", I use .net version

Comment: Yes, that's the right one, see http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.dtd Also check similar post at http://www.wentsch.me/configure-ckeditor-allow-enterting-empty-tags

Comment: dtd file's content is moved into ckeditor.js file in .net version and it is compressed (almost impossible to edit). may be ckeditor guys assumed .net developers don't need custom tags.

Comment: What version do you use?

Comment: Did you try to use config.protectedSource? http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.protectedSource `config.protectedSource.push( /(]+>[\s|\S]*?<\/asp:[^\>]+>)|(]+\/>)/gi );   // ASP.Net code`

Answer (score 0):

CKEditor's protectedSource feature solved my problem. the custom tag sits in regular html code and CKEditor ignores it which is exactly what I want. I will be using CKEditor for text modification only.

```
//example custom tag: <inc:module src="module_name" runat="server" />

// protect <inc:* /></*
config.protectedSource.push(/<([\S]+)[^>]*inc:*>.*<\/\1>/g);
// protect <inc:* />
config.protectedSource.push(/<[^>]+inc:[^>\/]*\/>/g);
```